Limiting current with an NPN for a 'safer' tube amplifier
Relatively new to electrical engineering broadly so please excuse any confusion, etc. Here to learn!
I am working on the layout for a stereo direct coupled tube amplifier. The schematic (below) is by Nobu Shishido and while it was previously published in a Japanese audio magazine, I found it in Sound Practices Issue 15 (pg. 16) in an article titled "I Never Met A 2A3 Amp That I Didn't Like" By Editor Joe Roberts.



It is a classic design that I would like to explore; however, this typology has a potential safety concern.
It is best described via tubecad.com:

The advantages are that many fewer parts are needed, as no coupling capacitor is used and the output tube and output transformer primary's inductance shield the input tube from the power-supply noise. Okay, what is not to like here? The danger we face is that if the input tube is faulty or missing from its socket, the output tube becomes over biased.

The author proposes a solution using an NPN transistor and a sensing resistor. The original article can be found at: https://www.tubecad.com/2015/12/blog0335.htm.




The added NPN transistor and current-sense resistor, Rs, impose a current limit. Once the idle current is sufficient to develop a large enough voltage drop across resistor Rs to turn on the NPN transistor, the transistor's collector will pull down the output tube's grid voltage. I would set the trip current to about 125% of the desired idle current. For example, if an idle current flow of 80mA is desired, then 100mA is the trip current. Under normal operation, the NPN transistor is turned off and effectively out of the circuit. This transistor would also save the day, should the output tube become gassy and conduct too much current. An LED could be placed in series wit the transistor's collector, as it would function as an error-condition indicator.

I imagine implementing the transistor as depicted in the modified schematic below; however, I am having a hard time understanding how to find the value of Rs. There is 65mA of current from the 2A3 tube to ground and I would like to limit to around 20% over so that in the case of driver tube failure - as described above - the NPN would switch and the output tube wouldn't melt. Additionally, I am not familiar with how to spec a NPN transistor for this application.
Any help in determining the value of Rs and the spec and type of NPN transistor would be immensely helpful.



(Schematic modified from the one at the top of the page, originally from: Sound Practices Issue 15 (pg. 16) in an article titled "I Never Met A 2A3 Amp That I Didn't Like" By Editor Joe Roberts)


NPN Vce > 600V, Rs ~ 0.7/Ilimit.

Be sure that 20% over Ibias is a good target for the overcurrent.  What is the large signal AC current in the tube as a percentage of Ibias?  Be sure you aren't clipping the audio signal in normal operation.  Component tolerances will eat in to this percentage as well.



The 20% figure was a bit arbitrary and based upon the article suggesting this approach with NPN. I’m hoping to understand how to calculate the value of Rs in order to trigger the NPN if there is too much current.

Vbe of an active biased NPN is about 0.7V, which is where I got the number for Rs = 0.7/Ilimit.  That value has a negative temperature coefficient, so the current limit will drop as the amplifier heats up.

If I understand the implementation of the NPN and sensing resistor (Rs), the resistor would sense the overcurrent, there would be a voltage drop and the NPN would switch. I understand the NPN needs to see .7V to switch (VBE). The value for resistor Rs should be in Ohms, correct? Again new to this so I’m confused as to what “0.7/Ilimit” means.

If you want a current limit of 100mA, Rs=0.7V/100mA = 7 ohms.   Another note, the NPN does not 'switch' on fully.  As it turns on, it pulls down on the tube grid, which will start to turn the tube off, decreasing the cathode current and decreasing the voltage across the 7 ohm sense resistor.  This is a negative feedback loop.   The circuit limits the tube current, it doesn't shut down the output stage in the event of a bad or no input tube.

My goal is to not destroy the output tube and things downstream (cathode resistor, etc.) if an input tube fails or is removed. My understanding is that  decreasing the current and voltage on the cathode of the output tube would prevent this from happening. Is there any downside to this approach? Its implementation has not been well documented in the tube amp community. Also, is the placement of the NPN and are correct in the last image?

I believe I found a suitable NPN (VCEO = 600V, VCBO = 1.2kV, VEBO = 12V, Pd = 50W,  Max DC Collector Current = 2A). Finally, is the placement of the NPN and Rs correct in the last image?

Yes, you have the NPN terminals  labeled correctly.

A quick follow up... Does my calculation for the power rating of the sensing resistor make sense?
My calculation for the sensing resistor is as follows:
Rs=.7V/.075mA = 9.3333 ohms
My calculation for the power rating is as follows:
.075mA^2 x 9.3333 ohms = .0523125 W

Yes, that formula works.
